# Xamarin Android application to Sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin

I'm a developer and currently, I'm learning how to connect android xamarin app to Sql server. I found 1 video in youtube but I'm not sure if the approach is correct.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZ8HNJMXXg

in this video, The creator connected directly to the db using the mainActivity. I'm wondering if there's a risk in doing so. I've read before that I need to connect using the RestAPI but in this video, all the comments were positive so I don't know if this is right or wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends heavily on what the purpose of the app is. For private use only by you and no external connection through the internet it might be ok. But for public available apps it is a no go. The reason is that you have make your database server public available to fire your queries directly against the database without any security or integration checks. This is not what you really want to do.